# JTextField - separation of numbers (ArrayList)

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextfield

Is there any way to take several different numbers using JTextField?

For example, following numeric values are given: 2.0, 3.0, 4.0. I would like to put them into ArrayList separately.

How to handle incorrect input data ​​in order to continue the typing?

```
    //in this case the resulst is "arList: 1.92239991"
    textField = new JTextField("1.9, 223, 9991");
    textField.addActionListener(this);
    ArrayList<Double> arList = new ArrayList<>();

    String str = textField.getText();
    String result = str.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    String otherResult = result.replaceAll(",","");
    double d = Double.parseDouble(otherResult);
    System.out.println(d);

    arList.add(d);
    for (Double anArList : arList) {
        System.out.println("arList: " +anArList);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the numbers are always separated by `,` you can use `String#split`, which will return an array of values.

```
String str = textField.getText();
String[] parts = str.split(",");
```

This will return each value between the `,`, including the white space.  You could then trim these results...

```
for (int index = 0; index < parts.length; index++) {
    parts[index] = parts[index].trim();
}
```

This will now contain just the remaining text.  If you must have it in a list you can use...

```
List<String> values = Arrays.asList(parts);
```

If you need it as list of `Double`s, you will need to parse each element indiviudally...

```
List<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>(parts.length);
for (String value : values) {
    values.add(Double.parseDouble(value));
}
```

This will still throw a parse exception if any one of the values is not a valid `Double`.

A better solution might be to use a `JFormattedTextField` or `JSpinner` to collect the individual value and add each one to a list one at a time (could display them in a `JList`), this would allow you to validate each value as it is entered.

Have a look at [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you for answer. The problem was that I had to use a JTextField. Allow to enter only numbers, spaces and commas is sufficient protection? I mean ensuring continuity of data entry.

Comment: You could use a DocumentFilter to limit what the user enters, but they can still enter nonuse like 1.2.3.4 which is meaningless

Answer (score 1):

if the format is fixed then you can use String.split():

```
String text = "1.9,  223,  9991";
for (String s: text.split("\\,\\s")) {
    double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
    System.out.println(d);
}
```